# Issues calling a method with multiple arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and Rails so sorry if this looks too noob. 
I have created a resource called stream and another resource called tasks and have mapped them properly using has_many and belong_to. Everything works until I decided to add a "Quick Task Add form" on my Stream.show view:

Here is the view code for the form:

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :title %>  <%= f.submit "Add Task" %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:stream_id, @stream.id) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my Stream.show action:

```
def show
  @stream = Stream.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find(@stream.user_id)
  @tasks = @stream.tasks.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  @title = @stream.title
  @task = Task.new
end
```

And here is my task controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @stream  = Stream.find(params[:stream_id])
    @stream.tasks.create!({:title => params[:task][:title], :user_id => 1, :owner => 1})

    if @stream.save
      flash[:success] = "Task created succesfully!"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating task"
    end

    redirect_to @stream
  end
end
```

Looks pretty basic to me. The problem is when it executes tasks.create, I get the following error message: "Validation failed: User can't be blank, Owner can't be blank"

What am I doing wrong?

*edit: adding model code from comment*

```
class Stream < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :title 
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy 
  validates :title, :presence=> true, :length => { :maximum =>50 } 
  validates :user_id, :presence => true 
end 

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :title 
  belongs_to :stream 
  validates :title, :presence=> true, :length => { :maximum =>70 } 
  validates :user_id, :presence => true 
  validates :owner, :presence => true 
  validates :stream_id, :presence => true 
  default_scope :order => "updated_at" 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your `user_id` and `owner` fro STREAM object

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @stream  = Stream.find(params[:stream_id])
    @stream.tasks.create!({:title => params[:task][:title], :user_id => 1, :owner => 1})
    @stream.user_id = 1
    @stream.owner = 1
    if @stream.save
      flash[:success] = "Task created succesfully!"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating task"
    end

    redirect_to @stream
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i can't test my suggestion currently but you might have to add

```
Attr_accessible :user,:owner
```

To the task model because you are mass-assigning these field using the hash.